# Hilt error by providing base url for Mockwebserver

Tags: android, dependency-injection, automated-tests, dagger-hilt

In my application I use Hilt for dependency injection. I implemented a `RetrofitModule` to provide dependencies for it in my Repository like this:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object RetrofitModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesRetrofitClient(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, baseUrl: String): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    fun providesBaseUrl(application: MyApplication): String {
        return application.getBaseUrl()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        val okHttpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }
        okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        return okHttpClientBuilder.build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesService(retrofit: Retrofit): MyService {
        return retrofit.create(MyService::class.java)
    }
}
```

To provide a test base url for Mockwebserver configuration under test I implemented the functions inside the `MyApplication` and `MyApplicationTest` class

**MyApplication.class**

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    fun getBaseUrl() = "https://www.foo-production.com"
}
```

**MyApplicationTest.class**

```
class MyApplicationTest : Application() {
    fun getBaseUrl() = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
}
```

But when I build the app I'm getting this error:

```
 A binding with matching key exists in component: de.xxx.xxx.MyApplication_HiltComponents.ApplicationC
      ...
```

I think the problem is this method

```
@Provides
fun providesBaseUrl(application: MyApplication): String {
    return application.getBaseUrl()
}
```

and there is a problem by providing MyApplication class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A) Probable fix for your case

Hilt is not able to provide your exact `MyApplication` instance, it's only able to provide a generic `Application` instance (see `Component default bindings` from [Hilt Components](https://dagger.dev/hilt/components.html)).

This should fix the issue:

```kotlin
@Provides
fun providesBaseUrl(application: Application): String {
    return (application as MyApplication).getBaseUrl()
}
```

That being said, there's a much more elegant way to implement that.

### B) The elegant way

1. In `src/main/your/package/` create one `UrlModule.kt`

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object UrlModule {

    @Provides
    fun providesBaseUrl(application: MyApplication): String {
        return "https://www.foo-production.com"
    }

}
```

2. In `src/test/your/package/` (or `src/androidTest/your/package/` if it's for UI tests) create the other `UrlModule.kt`

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object UrlModule {

    @Provides
    fun providesBaseUrl(application: MyApplication): String {
        return "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
    }

}
```

Comment: After trying the same, I've not managed to make it work. I created a **BaseUrlModule** for both *src/main/* and *src/androidTest* and my UI tests get just the one injected in *src/main/* Any idea?